# Linked list in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, linked-list

I have `Parent` and `Child` models. Parent `has_many :children`, which should be saved in database in correct order. I decided to save it like a linked list with field `next_id`. I know, that there is `acts_as_list` gem, but it saves `position` field. Isn't it more sql-heavy solution?

Nevertheless, have you any ideas how can I architect it? I want to save [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so all manipulations with list should be in `Child` model. `Parent` should get already ordered `children`.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of having all elements in a list related to a singular parent is you can fetch and order them in one pass:

```
SELECT * FROM list_items WHERE parent_id=? ORDER BY position
```

You cannot do this with a linked-list structure. Instead you must fetch, at most, two at a time, the previous and next entries, and this process must be repeated, recursively, for all other records in the list. Retrieving a list of 1000+ items would be impractical.

Comment: And what about `move` operation in such list? Isn't it heavy?

Comment: It's implemented as something like `UPDATE list_items SET position=position+1 WHERE parent_id=? AND position>?` to make a hole to renumber the moved item into, which is not as bad as you'd think. A linked list is faster for insertion, but if you ever want to retrieve the entire list you're basically hosed.